# Can we control the data sending by Phasor Measurement Unit (PMU)?

Tags: power-supply, power-engineering, instrumentation, power-grid

Since PMU send the data after sampling the data to the PDC. Can we design any scheme so that PMU send the data to PDC only when I want? That means to reduced the communication bandwidth can we design any scheme to the PMU so that PMU send the data only where there is any fault?

Comment: Unanswerable other than "yes".

Comment: I mean to say that can I use PMU as a smart sensor in Event Triggered technique in which PMU use as a event generator and then send the signal to PDC. @Andyaka

Comment: There is no context to this question. There are no links to equipment that you are talking about. "Can I use" or "can we design" questions inevitably bring an answer of "yes" because the context is too open or unresolved or unconstrained to make any other answer.

Comment: How I can do this? What is the process? Is it possible do all computation (Prony Analysis, Pencil Matrix etc) in PMU,since order of the matrix is very high. @Andyaka

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I can make a guess what you are talking about but I'm not going to do that. For instance, you have tagged "power-supply" and that tag-detail is this: *An electronic device which supplies electrical energy to a load. Can be AC or DC input. Typically DC output.* - so start by drawing a picture showing how the power supply interacts with the unspecified devices you talk about.

Comment: As Andy says, the answer - the ONLY answer - is Yes. Good luck with your project.